# Is there line numbering for nano?

Tags: nano

Is there a way to turn on line numbering for nano?

Comment: Please consider accepting the actual valid up-to-date answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324868/126755

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The only thing coming close to what you want is option to display your current cursor position. You activate it by using `--constantshow` (manpage: Constantly show the cursor position) option or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on an open text file.

Comment: Good answer. The --const argument is the same as -c. Use it to open the file like this: nano -c filename . Also, to make it permanent, include the 'set const' option in your ~/.nanorc file, which may not exist until you create it.

Answer (score 54):

Adding `set linenumbers` in `/etc/nanorc` works for me in `nano` version **2.7.1**.

It also can be activated [with `-l` or `--linenumbers`](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Command_002dline-Options) on the command line.

Toggle the line numbers from within nano with: `M-#` in my case <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: In addition to change the background color of the line numbers, I use `set numbercolor ,normal`

Comment: It may be preferable to store the `set linenumbers` in `/home/<user>/.nanorc` as a user preference instead.

Comment: I like this but it should be noted that when you copy and paste multiple lines, the line numbers will also copy and paste.

Answer (score 6):

This was added on the 20th of October and was documented on the 22nd of October and has yet to make it into a release so compile it from source like so:

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/nano.git;cd nano;./autogen.sh;./configure;sudo make install
```

Then add the following to your .nanorc:

```
set linenumbers
```

You can use ^# to turn line numbers on and off from within Nano. It's probably a bit buggy since it's recent and hasn't been tested by many people.

Answer (score 3):

It's 2021. The OP's question is still valid, but many of the answers here are for an older version of `nano`. I'm not presenting this answer as ["the last word"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/last+word) - only as an update.

> The default screen of nano consists of five areas. From top to bottom these are: the title bar, a blank line, the edit window, the status bar, and two help lines.

### Where to display line numbers?

Line numbers may be displayed in one of two places:

1. the edit window
2. the status bar

The status bar display simply updates the line number (and column) of the cursor/insertion point as it's moved about in the edit window. Line numbers in the edit window are positioned in the left margin. It is possible to display the line number in either or both the edit window and the status bar.

### Display line numbers in the edit window:

There are several methods (this is not necessarily a complete list):

#### 1. before the file is opened:

Edit/create the file `~/.nanorc` with the following line:

```
set linenumbers
```

#### 2. when the file is opened:

Use the `-l` option in `nano`:

```
$ nano -l <myfilename>
```

#### 3. after the file is opened:

Toggle line numbers "on" and "off" w/ `alt-shift-#`:

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>

### Display line numbers in the status bar:

#### 1. before the file is opened:

Edit/create the file `~/.nanorc` with the following line:

```
set constantshow
```

#### 2. when the file is opened:

Use the `-c` option in `nano`:

```
$ nano -c <myfilename>
```

#### 3. after the file is opened:

Toggle line number display in the status bar "on" and "off" w/ `alt-shift-C` (for Mac keyboard it's shift-esc-3):

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> for Mac keyboard)

### Summary

These all work as of today: Ubuntu 20.04, `nano --version` = GNU nano, version 4.8, although there are minor discrepancies in [the documentation.](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nano.html)

Comment: It should be noted that if you copy and paste multiple lines when line numbers are displayed on the edit window, the numbers for the lines will also copy and paste.

Comment: That may be a function of **a.** *how you do the copy*, and **b.** *which version of `nano`*. I don't get the line numbers unless I use my macOS' copy & paste from `nano` to the text edit app. I don't have time to test all the permutations now, but I will say that if `nano`'s copy & paste (i.e. all within `nano`) includes the line numbers, then that seems pretty weak - to my way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Nano is by design a very simple editor with few features. If you start wishing for anything beyond basic edition, nano isn't the right tool. [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) is a very powerful editor; to switch line numbers on, type [`M-x linum-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Minor-Modes.html). If Emacs scares you and you want a text mode editor, consider [Joe](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/), where line numbers are switched on with the `-linums` option.

That being said, [line numbering was eventually added five years after this question was asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324868).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, a quick alias in .bashrc:

```
echo "alias nano='nano -c -l'" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && reset
```

Forcing the syntax seems mandatory for hashbang scripts, so to force a particular highlighting:

```
echo "alias nano='nano --syntax=php -c -l'" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && reset
```

[man nano](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nano)

Answer (score 0):

For **Mac** users and **nano 6.1** (the version is important) press <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to toggle on/off line numbering on the edit window.

Comment: MacOS no longer bundles GNU Nano, it is now aliased to Pico

Answer (score 0):

Following will work on older versions of nano as well:

```
nano -c file.c
```

Once nano opens the file, press the arrow keys to move the cursor around to see line, col, char, etc. displayed towards the bottom.